# Fast way to split lists by value?

Tags: python, list, optimization

Is there any way to split a list at a certain value - essentially a string.split() for lists. Example:

```
[1, 2, 4, 3, 5, 2, 5]
```

would return

```
[[1], [4, 3, 5], [5]]
```

I can think of a few solutions which would be slow, but I am using this in an attempt to speed up code, and so if it would run slowly on lists of about length 10,000 small (single-digit) numbers then it won't really help, I've thought of a simple solution like

```
list1 = [1, 2, 4, 3, 5, 2 etc.]
list2 = []
for i, val in enumerate(list1):
    if val == 2:
         list2.append([])
    else:
         list2[len(list2)-1].append(val)
```

but I'm not sure this is really very fast. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) for this. It's easy to read, fast, and memory efficient with longer lists:

```
from itertools import groupby

l = [1, 2, 4, 3, 5, 2, 5]

[list(g) for k, g in groupby(l, key=lambda x: x!=2) if k]
# [[1], [4, 3, 5], [5]]
```

Comment: this is brilliant, did not know this groupby function exists XD

Comment: Oh my, I'm seconds late.

Answer (score 0):

well what I can think of is to use list.index() and slicing.

```
sep = somevalue
result = []
while sep in yourlist:
    sep_index = list.index(sep)
    result.append(list[:sep_index])
    result = result[sep_index+1:]
```

This should separate a long list by whatever sep value you set

Comment: This is not efficient, esp `index` in a loop. Moreover, I don't think using `index` helps here.